# ReferenceError: ClassicEditor is not Defined (ckeditor5, ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, ckeditor5

Yesterday I downloaded the Classic Editor of build ckeditor5 (version 40) from the official website and am struggling to implement it into my ASP.NET MVC website. Following [their .NET tutorial](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/integrations/dotnet.html), I attempted to create a simple WYSIWYG editor, but am regularly running into the `ReferenceError: ClassicEditor is not Defined` message that I have seen others run into with CKEditor5, even after downloading and attempting to mimic the MRE for the ClassicEditor from their website.

Here is what my code looks like, noting that multiple Bootstrap and jQuery links are handled by a core library outside of this repository, meaning scripts are typically loaded into their own Razor `@RenderSection`:

```
@section Scripts {
  <script src="/js/ckeditor.js"></script>
  <script>
    ClassicEditor
      .create($('#ckeditor'))
      .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
      });
  </script>
}
<div class="row form-group">
  <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <textarea class="ckeditor" id="ckeditor"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Some of the suggestions I tried already include:

1. Replacing `/js/ckeditor.js` with [the CDN link](https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/40.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js)
2. Placing the ClassicEditor inside and outside of a jQuery `$(function(){})`
3. Setting `window.ClassicEditor=ClassicEditor` in the script
4. Setting `var ClassicEditor = require('js/ckeditor')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the `<script src="/js/ckeditor.js"></script>` line seemed to be ignored is because, as was dictated by the core library, scripts are typically handled in a Razor `@RenderSection`, which was not acknowledging the *ckeditor.js* file when it was entered in, causing the title error.

The fix for this was to place the *ckeditor.js* file outside the `@RenderSection` like so:

```
<script src="/js/ckeditor.js"></script>
@section Scripts {
  <script>
    ClassicEditor
      .create($('#ckeditor'))
      .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
      });
  </script>
}
```

With this fix, the ClassicEditor works exactly as intended.